# Array undefined in D3.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I have a Rails model which can have children, an example in JSON looks like this:

```
{"content":"123",
 "created_at":"2013-08-23T22:17:03Z",
 "folder_id":4,
 "id":135,
 "parent_id":null,
 "title":"Will this succeed? 1234",
 "updated_at":"2013-08-23T22:17:03Z",
 "user_id":2,
 "children":
   [{"content":"123","created_at":"2013-09-05T03:52:05Z","folder_id":4,"id":189,"parent_id":135,"title":"123","updated_at":"2013-09-05T03:52:05Z","user_id":2}]
}
```

My problem is that each of these JSON objects is turned into a D3 node, and I need to be able to take actions based on whether or not the `children` array is empty. However, I performed a console.log on `submissions.children` and it comes back `undefined`. Why is that?

**Update**
Here's the show action in my submissions controller:

```
def show 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.json {render json: @submission.as_json(include:[:children])}
        format.html 
    end
end
```

Comment: how do you serialize your model to JSON?

Comment: Updated the post with that info.

Comment: have you try using debugger or repl (irb, rails console) to see what is the result hash from `as_json`? Unless you override `children` to return nil instead of empty array I can't really see why it will turn into `undefined`.

Comment: Could you show us your Javascript code as well please?